# Soundcloud custom player event on track end

Tags: jquery, html, soundcloud

I've been having problems with the custom soundcloud HTML 5 soundcloud player that I got from here: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player

What I'm trying to do is load the soundcloud player as individual tracks in a fullscreen slideshow. At the end of each track, I would like an event to trigger that clicks the navigation button, then starts the next player (because of the way the slider is set up, it won't automatically read the 'next track' and instead should be able to find the next individual 'play' button and click it)

I've gotten some makeshift ideas to work

```
$(document).bind('onPlayerPause.scPlayer', function(event){
$('.next').click();
});
```

Really basic and it indeed clicks functions that way it is written. However, because the event triggers when the player pauses, it also clicks the '.next' when I click the 'play' button to pause.

To summarize:

Find the event handler that sees when the track ends, not when it is paused and successfully implement it into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this in soundclousd-custom-player docs:

> `onMediaTimeUpdate.scPlayer`
>
> gets triggered constantly when the player
>   is playing, could be used to display track progress outside of the
>   player node

```
$(document).bind('onMediaTimeUpdate.scPlayer', function(event){
    console.log(event.target, 'the track is at ' + event.position + ' out of ' + 
    event.duration + ' which is ' + event.relative + ' of the total'); 
});
```

You have to trigger your event when `event.relative` equals to 100% or when `event.positon` equals to `event.duration`.

Comment: Ah, this is actually what I thought about doing but it seems so roundabout. I actually solved my own question with this method:

 $(document)
          .bind('scPlayer:onMediaEnd', function(event){
    $('.next').click();
    });

For whatever reason the onMediaEnd event wasn't triggering in my code but does now. :) Thank you so much. :)